# What is the best way to store the multiple data of single student in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a project online campus drive. in students profile i need to store the certificates in the database uploaded by students. I tried to store in the separate table with foreign key, the problem is if we use foreign key only one certificate can be uploaded for one student, if the student uploads second certificate i cannot store it because of using foreign key to refer the record. whether there is any other way to store the multiple data of single student in mysql database?

Comment: Can you show what you currently have as it should be a good start.

Comment: @NigelRen Currently i have two tables in database register and studentform in register i have **name, emailid, category, Address, Password, confirmpassword, registered_time, sessionid, image, login_time, logout_time** in studentform i have **department, year, semester, rollno and emailid with foreign key references emailid in register table** and now where can i store the certificates ans skills of a student. i need one-many relationship.

Comment: Okay. the `emailid` is the natural key identifying a student. They have an address and a password, etc. Why, though, does a student have one `login_time` and one `logout_time`? This doesn't seem to make sense in that table. Then there is the `studentform` table. What does it represent? I see there is the `emailid` and a `semester`, so is there one row per student and semester in that table? And then, which of the two tables shall the documents refer to?

Comment: It may be beneficial to rename your tables, so they tell better what they contain. It seems the `register` table is really the `student` table. Or can one student register multiple times? Then you'd need one `student` table and one `student_register` table. And if the `studentform` represents the students' semesters, then `student_semester` might be a good name. If it represents something else, use another appropriate name. By calling the tables thus, it is usually easier to work with them, to place columns where they belong and the database and queries become less prone to semantical errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, foreign key is exactly what should be working for you. Tables:

- student (student_id, name, ...)
- document (document_id, student_id, ...)

The document table has a student_id, which is a foreign key to the student table. That establishes the 1:n relation that you need.

Answer (score 0):

It's about one-to-many/one-to-one relationship.

In your case, you are using one-to-one relation, but you need one-to-many.

To use required relation, I suggest you to do this:

Student:

```
id: bigint AI PK
<all student fields>
```

Certificate:

```
id: bigint AI PK
student: Foreign key to Student#id
<all certificate fields>
```

You, to get all certificate of one student:

```
SELECT * FROM certificate WHERE student = myStudentID;
```